# How to get source code of function that is wrapped by a decorator?

Tags: python, decorator, python-2.x, python-decorators

I wanted to print the source code for `my_func`, that is wrapped by `my_decorator`:

```
import inspect
from functools import wraps

def my_decorator(some_function):
    @wraps(some_function)
    def wrapper():
        some_function()

    return wrapper

@my_decorator
def my_func():
    print "supposed to return this instead!"
    return

print inspect.getsource(my_func)
```

However, it returns source for wrapper instead:

```
@wraps(some_function)
def wrapper():
    some_function()
```

Is there a way for it to print the following instead?

```
def my_func():
    print "supposed to return this instead!"
    return
```

Note that the above is abstracted from a larger program. Of course we can just get rid of the decorator in this example, but that's not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Python 2, the `@functools.wraps()` decorator does not set the convenience `__wrapped__` attribute that the [Python 3 version](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) adds (new in Python 3.2).

This means you'll have to resort to extracting the original function *from the closure*. Exactly at what location will depend on the exact decorator implementation, but picking the first function object should be a good generalisation:

```
from types import FunctionType

def extract_wrapped(decorated):
    closure = (c.cell_contents for c in decorated.__closure__)
    return next((c for c in closure if isinstance(c, FunctionType)), None)
```

Usage:

```
print inspect.getsource(extract_wrapped(my_func))
```

Demo using your sample:

```
>>> print inspect.getsource(extract_wrapped(my_func))
@my_decorator
def my_func():
    print "supposed to return this instead!"
    return
```

Another option is to update the `functools` library to add a `__wrapped__` attribute for you, the same way Python 3 does:

```
import functools

def add_wrapped(uw):
    @functools.wraps(uw)
    def update_wrapper(wrapper, wrapped, **kwargs):
        wrapper = uw(wrapper, wrapped, **kwargs)
        wrapper.__wrapped__ = wrapped
        return wrapper

functools.update_wrapper = add_wrapped(functools.update_wrapper)
```

Run that code **before** importing the decorator you want to see affected (so they end up using the new version of `functools.update_wrapper()`). 
You'll have to manually unwrap still (the Python 2 `inspect` module doesn't go looking for the attribute); here's a simple helper function do that:

```
def unwrap(func):
    while hasattr(func, '__wrapped__'):
        func = func.__wrapped__
    return func
```

This will unwrap any level of decorator wrapping. Or use a copy of the [`inspect.unwrap()` implementation from Python 3](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Lib/inspect.py#L458-L488), which includes checking for accidental circular references.

Comment: For Python 2, would it not also be relatively easy to write your own `wraps()` decorator that defined said "convenience" attribute? Seem like that code might work in Python 3 even though not necessary (i.e. it would be portable)?

Comment: @martineau: provided you control the source code of the decorator you can easily swap out the `wraps()` implementation, sure. You probably can monkey-patch `functools.update_wrapper` too.

Answer (score 3):

As Martijn Pieters points out in his answer, the Python 2 `@functool.wraps()` decorator doesn't define a `__wrapped__` attribute, which would make doing what you want to do very easy. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=__wrapped__#functools.update_wrapper) I read, even though it was added in Python 3.2, there was a [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue17482) in the ways it was sometimes handled until version 3.4 was released—so the code below uses v3.4 as the cut-off for defining a custom `wraps()` decorator.

Since from its name it sounds like you have control over `my_decorator()`, you can workaround the issue by defining you're own `wraps`-like function, rather than extracting the original function from the closure, as shown in his answer. Here's how to do it (which works in Python 2 and 3):

<sup>(As Martijn also points out, you could monkey-patch the change in by overwriting the `functools.wraps` module attribute, which would make the change also affect other modules that use `functools` instead of only the one where it's defined.)</sup>

```
import functools
import inspect
import sys

if sys.version_info[0:2] >= (3, 4):  # Python v3.4+?
    wraps = functools.wraps  # built-in has __wrapped__ attribute
else:
    def wraps(wrapped, assigned=functools.WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS,
              updated=functools.WRAPPER_UPDATES):
        def wrapper(f):
            f = functools.wraps(wrapped, assigned, updated)(f)
            f.__wrapped__ = wrapped  # set attribute missing in earlier versions
            return f
        return wrapper

def my_decorator(some_function):
    @wraps(some_function)
    def wrapper():
        some_function()

    return wrapper

@my_decorator
def my_func():
    print("supposed to return this instead!")
    return

print(inspect.getsource(my_func.__wrapped__))
```

Output:

```
@my_decorator
def my_func():
    print("supposed to return this instead!")
    return
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a need to retrieve the original function that has been decorated multiple times. I wrote the following code that will try to unwrap until it gets to a function that hasn't been decorated.

```
def extract_wrapped(decorated):
    closure = decorated.__closure__
    if closure:
        for cell in closure:
            if isinstance(cell.cell_contents, FunctionType) and cell.cell_contents.__closure__ is None:
                return cell.cell_contents
            elif isinstance(cell.cell_contents, FunctionType):
                return extract_wrapped(cell.cell_contents)
    return decorated
```

You can use the extract_wrapped function to get the original function that has been decorated. For example:

```
import inspect
from types import FunctionType


def decorator(func):
    def wrapper():
        print("before")
        func()
        print("after")
    return wrapper


@decorator
@decorator
def my_function():
    print("func")


print("Decorated:")
my_function()
# before
# before
# func
# after
# after


def extract_wrapped(decorated):
    closure = decorated.__closure__
    if closure:
        for cell in closure:
            if isinstance(cell.cell_contents, FunctionType) and cell.cell_contents.__closure__ is None:
                return cell.cell_contents
            elif isinstance(cell.cell_contents, FunctionType):
                return extract_wrapped(cell.cell_contents)
    return decorated


original = extract_wrapped(my_function)

print("\nOriginal source:")
print(inspect.getsource(original))
# @decorator
# @decorator
# def my_function():
#     print("func")

print("\nOriginal:")
original()
# func
```