# How to modify the return address in Python 2 (or achieve an equivalent result)

Tags: python-2.7

## Some background on why I want to achieve what I'm trying to achieve:

I am making a long-running server type application. I would like to be able to perform functional and integration style testing on this application with high coverage, especially in the failure and corner-case scenarios. In order to achieve this, I would like to inject various faults which are configurable at run time so that my test can validate the program's behavior when such a condition is hit.

---

### The Problem:

I would like to be able to dynamically decide the return behavior of a function. I would additionally like to do this with only a function call and without pre-processing the source code (macros). Here is a simple example:

```
from functools import wraps

def decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print 'in wrapper before %s' % func.__name__
        val = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print 'in wrapper after %s' % func.__name__
        return val

    return func_wrapper

@decorator
def grandparent():
    val = parent()
    assert val == 2
    # do something with val here

@decorator
def parent():
    foo = 'foo_val'
    some_func(foo)
    # other statements here

    child()
    # if the condition in child is met,
    # this would be dead (not-executed)
    # code. If it is not met, this would
    # be executed.
    return 1

def child(*args, **kwargs):
    # do something here to make
    # the assert in grandparent true
    return 2

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

class MyClass:
    @decorator
    def foo(self):
        val = self.bar()
        assert val == 2

    def bar(self):
        self.tar()
        child()
        return 1

    def tar(self):
        return 42

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
```

The `grandparent()` function in the code above calls `parent()` to get a response. It would then do something based on the value of `val`. The `parent()` function calls `child()` and unconditionally returns the value `1`. I would like to write something in `child()` which causes the value it returns to be returned to `grandparent()` and skip processing the rest of `parent()`.

---

### Restrictions/Permissions

- `grandparent()` could be function number n in a long chain of function calls, not necessarily the top level function. Only
- `child()` and any new helper functions called solely as a result of calling `child()` can be modified/created to make this work.
- All work must be done at runtime. No pre-processing of the source files is acceptable
- The decision about the `parent()` function's behavior has to be decided inside of the specific `child()` call.
- Using pure Python (2.7) or making use of the cPython API are both acceptable ways to solve this issue.
- This is allowed to be a hack. The `child()` function will be inert in production mode.

---

### I have tried

- I have tried modifying the stack list (deleting the `parent()` frame) retrieved from inspect.stack(), but this seems to not do anything.
- I have tried creating new bytecode for the `parent()` frame and replacing it in the stack. This also does not seem to have an effect.
- I have tried looking into the cPython functions related to stack management, but when I added or removed a frame, I kept getting stack under or overflows.

Comment: To be clear: You want to write the function `parent()` exactly as above, but you want that it returns something different from `1`?

Comment: Correct @pschill, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to reinvent exceptions. Maybe you should use them instead of returning values.

Comment: Exceptions are no good for this. In order for that to be useful, I would have to raise an exception in child() with the value I want to return and catch it in grandparent(). Except I don't want to modify grandparent() this functionality.

Comment: cannot you monkey patch `parent()` to point to `child()` instead, before the module is used (immediately after it's imported)?

Comment: I need it to be more dynamic than that. I want child to do nothing based on some system state sometimes and I want it to perform the requested behavior at other times based on state (state that I control).

Comment: @Robert, but you control `child()` anyways. Or did you mean you wanted "`parent()`" to behave according to the system state that you control?

Comment: No, I want `child()` to behave according to some state. I want `parent()` to potentially run some statements on its own before it gets to the child call. And there will be many different `parent()` functions which call this same `child()`. If I'm not understanding your question, write it up in an answer where there's better formatting and more room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the name(s) of `child()`, then you can patch all `child()` callers at runtime by iterating through module and class functions, patching call sites to `child()` to add your custom logic, and hot-swapping callers of child with the patched version.

Here is a working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

from six import wraps

def decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print 'in wrapper before %s' % func.__name__
        val = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print 'in wrapper after %s' % func.__name__
        return val

    return func_wrapper

@decorator
def grandparent():
    val = parent()
    assert val == 2
    # do something with val here


@decorator
def parent():
    # ...
    # ...
    child()
    # if the condition in child is met,
    # this would be dead (not-executed)
    # code. If it is not met, this would
    # be executed.
    return 1


def child(*args, **kwargs):
    # do something here to make
    # the assert in grandparent true
    return 2

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

class MyClass:
    @decorator
    def foo(self):
        val = self.bar()
        assert val == 2

    def bar(self):
        self.tar()
        child()
        return 1

    def tar(self):
        return 42

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

import sys
import inspect
import textwrap
import types
import itertools
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def should_intercept():
    # TODO: check system state and return True/False
    # just a dummy implementation for now based on # of args
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        return True
    return False


def _unwrap(func):
    while hasattr(func, '__wrapped__'):
        func = func.__wrapped__
    return func


def __patch_child_callsites():
    if not should_intercept():
        return

    for module in sys.modules.values():
        if not module:
            continue

        scopes = itertools.chain(
            [module],
            (clazz for clazz in module.__dict__.values() if inspect.isclass(clazz))
        )

        for scope in scopes:
            # get all functions in scope
            funcs = list(fn for fn in scope.__dict__.values()
                         if isinstance(fn, types.FunctionType)
                         and not inspect.isbuiltin(fn)
                         and fn.__name__ != __patch_child_callsites.__name__)

            for fn in funcs:
                try:
                    fn_src = inspect.getsource(_unwrap(fn))
                except IOError as err:
                    log.warning("couldn't get source for fn: %s:%s",
                                scope.__name__, fn.__name__)
                    continue

                # remove common indentations
                fn_src = textwrap.dedent(fn_src)

                if 'child()' in fn_src:
                    # construct patched caller source
                    patched_fn_name = "patched_%s" % fn.__name__

                    patched_fn_src = fn_src.replace(
                            "def %s(" % fn.__name__,
                            "def %s(" % patched_fn_name,
                    )

                    patched_fn_src = patched_fn_src.replace(
                        'child()', 'return child()'
                    )

                    log.debug("patched_fn_src:\n%s", patched_fn_src)

                    # compile patched caller into scope
                    compiled = compile(patched_fn_src, inspect.getfile(scope), 'exec')
                    exec(compiled) in fn.__globals__, scope.__dict__

                    # replace original caller with patched caller
                    patched_fn = scope.__dict__.get(patched_fn_name)
                    setattr(scope, fn.__name__, patched_fn)

                    log.info('patched %s:%s', scope.__name__, fn.__name__)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    __patch_child_callsites()
    grandparent()
    MyClass().foo()
```

Run with no arguments to get the original behavior (assertion failure). Run with one or more arguments and the assertion disappears.

Comment: This is a good thought, I will have to try something like this out. Sometimes my `parent()` is a class method, sometimes it is a module function, etc. so I hope I can get something like this to work for those cases as well. Let me take some time to work on this angle and I'll accept if it works or come back with some clarifying questions.

Comment: I updated the answer to handle both modules and classes. See if it now fits your needs.

Comment: I've been having issues getting this solution to work when the functions/methods are decorated. Still working on it by trying to unwrap the function first using a method similar to the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43506378/how-to-get-source-code-of-function-that-is-wrapped-by-a-decorator.

Comment: I updated my initial post with an example that fails the test for `grandparent()`. Interestingly it still succeeds for `foo()` though.

Comment: It fails when `parent()` is decorated. But if `foo()` or `grandparent()` are decorated, there is no problem.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it now. I've modified your answer to handle the decorated functions. You'll see the same results with some printing in the decorators. Included the six library because I didn't want to monkeypatch functools.

Comment: I approved your edit. Accessing `__wrapped__` through `six` is the way to go for wrapped functions.