# Determine keywords of a tornado coroutine

Tags: python, tornado, inspect

I want to inspect a Tornado coroutine to see if it has certain keywords.  Normally I would do this with the `inspect` module, and in particular `inspect.signature`, which works great.  However in Python 2 (I have to support both) signature doesn't exist, so I'm looking for an alternative.  The standard `inspect.getargspec` doesn't work as desired.

```
In [1]: import inspect

In [2]: import tornado.gen

In [3]: class Foo(object):
   ...:     def a(self, x, y=None):
   ...:         pass
   ...:     
   ...:     @tornado.gen.coroutine
   ...:     def b(self, x, y=None):
   ...:         pass
   ...:     

In [4]: foo = Foo()

In [5]: inspect.getargspec(foo.a)
Out[5]: ArgSpec(args=['self', 'x', 'y'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=(None,))

In [6]: inspect.getargspec(foo.b)
Out[6]: ArgSpec(args=[], varargs='args', keywords='kwargs', defaults=None)

In [7]: import sys; sys.version_info
Out[7]: sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=14, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Is there a way, in Python 2, to answer questions like "does `foo.b` have a parameter named `y`?"

Comment: From tornado 4,  `gen.coroutine` saves original function into `__wrapped__` attribute and you can inspect it: `inspect.getargspec(f.b.__wrapped__)  # ArgSpec(args=['self', 'x', 'y'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=(None,))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the Python 2 standard library that can do this (but as you noted on Python 3 it works fine). You'll need to access the `__wrapped__` attribute yourself. As suggested in [Martijn Pieters' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43506509) to a similar question, you could use a copy of the `inspect.unwrap` function from Python 3 or a simplified version like

```
def unwrap(func):
    while hasattr(func, '__wrapped__'):
        func = func.__wrapped__
    return func
```